# Using grub to properly boot from an external backup drive

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, fstab

**edit**: I think I solved my own problem -- see bottom of question for details

I have a copy of all the files under `/` on an external usb-connected harddrive. To test whether this backup works, i'm trying to boot from it. However, this is proving a bit more difficult than I expected.

1. In what I assume is the BIOS, I select my external HD as the boot device. However, whether I select this device or my usual drive as the boot device, I am shown the same GRUB menu. This happens whether I manually went and installed GRUB on my external HD or not. So my question is, is GRUB being loaded from my normal boot drive or from the external drive, and does it matter?

   - I found that when using GRUB command line without GRUB installed on my external drive, the external drive was shown as `(hd2,gpt1)`, however after I installed GRUB on the external drive, it came up as `(hd0,gpt2)`.
2. Perhaps the difficulties I'm having are related to just my first question, but when I boot after specifying `linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda2`, I always get some failure relating to the drive specified as `root` not being found. This happens even when I specify root by device uuid. My question is, do I need to worry about

   - `/etc/fstab`? Is this something I need to change in order to make sure that root is found? And does it matter whether I change the `/etc/fstab` file on my internal drive or on the external one. (I did modify `/etc/fstab` on the external drive so that the drive with the UUID of the root partition should be mounted to `/`, but to no avail)
   - Perhaps because it is a usb connected external HD, do I need to do anything special? I noticed seeing the error `usb 2-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71` while booting normally, but since this has no apparent effect on the functionality of the drive, I ignored it. This error also appeared on two separate external HD docks, so I assume it is not a hardware issue.

---

Clarifications:

I created my external backup using [Borg](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which creates a copy of all the files. It doesn't copy the entire disk over like `dd`, so for example while installing grub I still need to manually create a partition with the `bios_grub` flag.

The exact command I use in grub while attempting to boot is

```
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
linux vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda2
initrd  initramfs-linux.img
boot
```

---

I've managed to boot.

I had tried both `linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda2` and `linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sdc2` to no avail -- the first because the drive was showing up as `(hd0,gpt2)` in grub, and the second because the partition gets labeled as `/dev/sdc2` when I boot normally. However, neither of these worked, and both dropped me into a strange command line. I discovered that the partition with the correct UUID was actually mounted to `/dev/sdb2` for some reason! Using `root=/dev/sdb2` I booted the system just fine. I think my previous attempts to boot by specifying UUID failed for one of various reasons (GRUB not being installed, typos in the UUID, etc).

This is pretty anticlimactic. I am still curious about the original questions I had -- namely, **1.** how it is decided which GRUB is used when there are multiple drives with GRUB installed? **2.** does `/etc/fstab` play a role in the booting process, or is it irrelevant? -- and I'll award the bounty for answers to those questions.

Comment: How did you create the USB? RSync? Can you show an example just to clarify.

Comment: Yes, I used [Borg](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to backup and extract a copy of my files onto the external HD. It backs up everything on the "file level", so it's not quite the same as using `dd`.

Comment: from what I read borg is a `BorgBackup (short: Borg) is a deduplicating backup program`, this doesn't sound appropriate for making a OS backup that you expect to be bootable, but I could be wrong. I would try RSync. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rsync#Full_system_backup

Comment: I backup everything under `/` using borg, so it should be at least as good as rsync in that respect. rsync probably also doesn't deal with deduplication or encryption, so it's not as suitable for making backups. I don't think it would solve my problem either, since my question deals with how grub works / how the booting process works -- questions I imagine I would still have if I used rsync.

Comment: 2 questions : are you using a regular BIOS or UEFI ? Did you make sure your initrd is able to access an usb device (the way to do it depends on your distribution) ?

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET I am using regular BIOS. I'm not sure how to check if my initrd can access a usb device, however i know if i write `initrd /boot/foobar` in grub i get an error about the file not being found, whereas `initrd /boot/initramfs.img` works fine, so i think that's a sign that initrd can access the files on my usb device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem is `root=/dev/sda2` because that is doing a mount by `device name` which is **not unique**.  If you have only one drive installed, then that will typically always show up as `/dev/sda` so no problem.  But install a second disk or any other thing in addition that shows up as `/dev/sd?` then there is no guarantee of the order of anything and oftentimes what was `sda` is moved down to `sdb`... can become messy quick and fail.

Best to mount via **by device-id** or **by-uuid** which will be unique.

Under `/dev/disk/` you will see folders like

- by-id/
- by-label/
- by-path/
- by-uuid/

And for example under `by-id/` you will see links such as

here is my `/etc/fstab` that mounts `by device-id` to give you an idea, i removed extra lines to keep it on point.  And I use EFI not GRUB, but the principle is the same just more elaborate with Grub {the grand part in grand unified boot loader}:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000cca070168a20-part2                    /           ext3    acl,user_xattr 1 1
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000cca070168a20-part1                    /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0002,utf8=true 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36003048018e26e011d81ba1714e4c99f-part1    /data       xfs     defaults 1 0
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36003048018fa44011d57b61bbe1b8533-part1    /scratch    xfs     defaults 1 0
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36003048018e266011d81ba7e1afeadf6-part1    /bkup       xfs        defaults              1 2
```

Note: this is what I see in SLES 11.4.  And while I use EFI, you need to find the specific items within GRUB or GRUB2 and modify.  As an example here is my `/boot/efi/efi/SuSE/elilo.conf` file, notice the `root=` part.  What corresponds to this in your GRUB you want to modify to be either `by device-id` or `by uuid`.  and don't forget to modify `/etc/fstab` to be by a unique method also either `by-id` or `by-uuid`.

```
# This file has been transformed by /sbin/elilo.
# Please do NOT edit here -- edit /etc/elilo.conf instead!
# Otherwise your changes will be lost e.g. during kernel-update.
#
# Modified by YaST2. Last modification on Mon Oct 15 11:04:42 EDT 2018
timeout = 80
##YaST - boot_efilabel = "SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4"
default = SLES11_SP4_16
prompt

image = vmlinuz-3.0.101-108.77-default
###Don't change this comment - YaST2 identifier: Original name: linux###
    label = SLES11_SP4_16
    append = "splash=verbose showopts                 "
    initrd = initrd-3.0.101-108.77-default
    root = /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000cca070168a20-part2

image = vmlinuz-3.0.101-108.77-default
###Don't change this comment - YaST2 identifier: Original name: failsafe###
    label = Failsafe_15
    append = "showopts ide=nodma apm=off noresume edd=off powersaved=off nohz=off highres=off processor.max_cstate=1 nomodeset x11failsafe                  "
    description = "Failsafe (3.0.101-108.77-default)"
    initrd = initrd-3.0.101-108.77-default
    root = /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000cca070168a20-part2
```

You do NOT want `boot=/dev/sd?` or `root=/dev/sd?` anywhere, where `?` is whatever letter.  Reference the disk out of `/dev/disk/by-id` or `/dev/disk/by-uuid`; you could even use `by-label` provided you set partition labels and trust them to be unique.

Comment: I love using Labels personally!

Answer (score 2):

This should answer your questions:

- Generally, the GRUB that is used is the one that is on the disk that is seen first by the BIOS or selected to be run first in BIOS. Because the MBR of the drive pionts to the GRUB that loads.
- The /etc/fstab is only responsible for automating the process of mounting, partitions.
  In curtain cases you can bypass the fstab completely.